# Tikz standalone image cropped

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I'm wondering why my standalone tikz picture gets cropped mid way through the picture? Code is shown below without the input data files.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    title={$F_x$ vs. Time},
                    xlabel={Time ($s$)},
                    ylabel={Force ($N$)},
                    width=100mm, height=80mm,
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=37.7,
                    xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25, 30, 35, 40},
                    xmajorgrids, xminorgrids, ymajorgrids,
                    legend style={
                        at={(0.05,0.97)}, 
                        anchor=north west, 
                        legend cell align=left
                        }
                ]
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `geometry` doesn't work very well with `standalone`, removing that package makes the PDF come out as expected. In this case there surely isn't any need for `geometry` anyway, so that's not a loss.