# Tikz standalone picture with graph cropped and not centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs, standalone

There is a problem with using the standalone output and plotting a simple tree graph with Tikz.
The image is neither correctly centralize nor cropped. I added a huge border to show at least something.

See my minimal working example and the output I get with LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019).

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[tikz, border=5cm]{standalone}

% Packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

% definitions of entries here
\def\ItemI{Lorem ipsum\\lorem ipsum\\lorem ipsum}
\def\ItemII{Lorem ipsum}
\def\ItemIII{Lorem ipsum}
\def\ItemIV{Lorem ipsum}
\def\ItemV{Lorem ipsum}
\def\ItemVI{Lorem ipsum}
\def\ItemVII{Lorem ipsum}

% Document
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikz[tree layout,
    % specifying the text width in nodes fails
    nodes={fill=blue!20, align=center},
    % specifying the text width in child node has no effect
    % every child node/.style={minimum height=1.8cm,text width=2.5cm}
    ]
    \graph[]{
      1[as=\ItemI] -> {
        11[as=\ItemII] -> {
          111[as=\ItemIII],
          112[as=\ItemIV],
        },
        12[as=\ItemV] -> {
          121[as=\ItemVI],
        },
        13[as=\ItemVII],
      },
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph non-centered and cropped]
I checked multiple comparable issues (e.g. [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53220/standalone-producing-cropped-truncated-formulae), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254577/tikz-standalone-image-cropped), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34590/standalone-package-creates-a-page-with-a-fixed-width)) but could not find a solution.

Comment: The problem is, that you say `\tikz[tree layout,....`. Delete that `\tikz`

Comment: If I leave that out, then the tree layout of course also vanishes but I would like to keep it.

Comment: I don't understand: `\tikz[...]` is something like a synonym to `\begin{tikzpicture}[...]`. You use both of them;  and you use `\tikz` inside `\begin{tikzpicture}`, that's rarely a good idea; and here it is wrong.

Comment: The `tree layout, ...` options do need to be supplied, but should be directly given as optional arguments of the `tikzpicture` environment. You need to supply them as `\begin{tikzpicture}[tree layout, ...`, the extra `\tikz` in there is, as cis says, is starting an additional TikZ picture which is messing up something.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: solved in comments in 2020 (!), spurious "\tikz".